# in wordpress 4.0 with buddypress how do I add a profile field that can only be changed by administrators

Tags: wordpress

I am running a club-based wordpress application.
In it has buddypress installed into it.

What I want to do, is add a profile field whose value can only be set by the administrator of the site.  I know how to add a custom field, but the default behavior is to allow the user to set it.  I don't want that.

Can this be done, and if so, how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [template overload](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/#overloading-template-compatibility-theme-files) of this file: 
`buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\profile\edit.php`

Untested, but try changing this:

```
$field_type = bp_xprofile_create_field_type( bp_get_the_profile_field_type() );
$field_type->edit_field_html();
```

To this:

```
$name = bp_get_the_profile_field_name();

if( $name == 'name of your field' ) {

   if( is_super_admin() ) {
      $field_type = bp_xprofile_create_field_type( bp_get_the_profile_field_type() );
      $field_type->edit_field_html();
   }
   else 
    echo $name . '<br/>' . bp_get_the_profile_field_value();

}
else {
    $field_type = bp_xprofile_create_field_type( bp_get_the_profile_field_type() );
    $field_type->edit_field_html();
}
```

Comment: This was brilliant!!  The only thing that got me was the first line. You forgot the () as it is a function, other than that, genius!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)? That's an easy way to add custom fields to the pages you want.

They have some documentation on how to [How to Hide ACF Menu from Clients](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-hide-acf-menu-from-clients/).